# Excel worksheets in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

Is there a way when to make the current worksheet your on in excel to be the worksheet shown when changing worksheets in vb.net? Say I'm on worksheet 1 and change it to worksheet 2 through vb.net, If I enter in data it will show up on worksheet two but in order to see the data I have to physically go to the excel file and select worksheet 2 in order to change the actually worksheet page being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this code and it seems to work on my side. The trick is the method `sheet.Activate()`

```
Sub Main
    Dim excelApp as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = _
                    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Try  
        Dim inFile As String = "D:\temp\test.xls"
        ' Show excel ' 
        excelApp.Visible = true
        Dim excelWorkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = _
                             excelApp.Workbooks.Open(infile)  

        Dim x as Integer 
        for x = excelApp.Sheets.Count to 1 step -1 
            Dim sheet as _Worksheet = CType(excelApp.Sheets(x), _Worksheet)
            sheet.Activate()   ' Activate the sheet'
            Thread.Sleep(5000) ' Sleep for 5 seconds to see the sheet'
        Next
        Finally  
            if excelApp IsNot Nothing then
                excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false
                'excelApp.Quit();  'remove the comment to close excel'
            End if
        End try
 End Sub
```

Comment: I have my xlWorksheet declared gloabally so I can access it when needed and I call this xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets("WK-" & i).Activate() and it changes the week on excel but then crashes with this error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'."

Comment: I fixed it, I took out "xlWorksheet =" and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks for your input it helped!

Comment: I suggest to split your line in two. First assign the `xlWorksheet` from the workbook and see if it works. Then, on a second line, use `xlWorksheet.Activate()`

Comment: Okay so I changed it to xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets("WK-" & i)
xlWorksheet.Activate() like you suggested but it works the same as xlWorkbook.Worksheets("WK-" & i).Activate(). Is there any real difference between the two since they work exactly the same?

Comment: No, there is no difference, I was only suggesting to split the line to get a better understanding where the error was. Glad you have solved anyway.